# How to identify webdriver frames?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

In Webdriver, how are frames identified?  I want to know the "windowHandle" of the current frame, but there is no "frameHandle".

This would really help with troubleshooting.

Comment: Are you talking about `iframe`?

Comment: Nope.  Old-school frames.